# Facebook app error - Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration

Tags: facebook

I've been doing a lot of facebook apps until now and everytime I had them on the same domain. No issues on any of them.

Now I started using another domain, I have the comodo SSL, but my apps are not working correct.

Evertything is setuped same like I did on the old domain.

Basically the first page of the app loads and than when I click to go to another page, I see in the link bar that it goes to:

```
http://domain.com/app_name/folder/request.php?code=AQCYkHOF0b3D755VtSWei498C13SvlF_bZ3GjUk8LnwBBQbaCAE9j1bPAkyyxId6hLbCv0-PuwfTkdjxn8sKmLnyL8ltYzg1nf5XD1lo1SPipHet-ZIMfuUWnqSmAJj9Mo2fB6mlUREBV7Lahh5k0MJTyERSDQ8IWrLJQqGmuq0oKe1L_IR1ZgIN1uLYmRXeq9ukRAFc463AcVXdIeLbkFmC2Y8nG8CdEshuA8oVWOgH9ezMFm0H8IVkcKKCJtDp9lSg6XxpL-5gHwPkxw5_e2xflEWrQp3NClBLNN9rOC4rY10yUqUrkTPMSAeGttnYwOo&state=ba25dbfe845349d548c04f6ba14deef8#_=_
```

redirects to the first page and in the console I get this message

```
Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings.  It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains.
```

I get this message in the console and when I open the app on the first page.

In the facebook developers I setuped the:
- canvas page
- website
- page tab

Practically I did same like I was doing on the old domain, now if I move the app on the old domain and modify the path in the facebook devleopers is working fine.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Did you set the new domain in the app settings as well? changing the canvas + page tab + website is not enough

Comment: Yes, my config file has the new domain everywhere.

Comment: what config file? I'm talking about the settings the http://developers.facebook.com (the answer is probably no - because this is the only reason for getting this error)

Comment: You mean App Domains? I never put anything there, and I tryed to put the domain name, basically I did a new app, I didn't modify a old app from the old domain.

Comment: So this is the problem - look at my full answer

Comment: I tryed this already before, but doesn't work.

Comment: Paste the code that you're running

Comment: My app is pretty big, it has like 50 files, the thing is that if I put the same files on the old server and domain and update the facebook developer settings, it works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the domains of the app in the developers site

If you try to run `FB.init` in the Javascript SDK from a page in a domain other that the ones you've set - you'll get this error

Note that you can only set domains that are mentioned in one of the following settings in the Facebook developers site:

- Canvas URL
- Website URL
- Page Tab URL

[image: Facebook developers center]

Setting the domain should be as follow:

If your app loads from `http://sub.domain.com/` you can put either `domain.com` or `sub.domain.com` - I recommended setting the highest level that you have administrative permissions for (if you're hosting on `http://myaccount.some-service.cloud-provider.com` don't put `cloud-provider.com` because if you do - all the other clients of that provider will be allowed to use your app id using the JavaScript SDK)

Comment: On all my 50+ fb apps I never put anything in app domains, I've tryed this on the new domain, but doesn't change anything.

Comment: You must put domain in order to user JavaScript SDK - and you must put domain to authorize the app using "server side" auth process (when you are redirecting the user to the allow page)

Comment: I put it, but it still same error, I think maybe is something related to the new server, because I changed server + doamin.

Comment: it has nothing to do with servers - this is done by Facebook reading the data that the browsers gives them - all client side

Comment: Ok, if i find the cause of the problem I will post it here.

Comment: There is only one cause possible - and this is using the app from unauthorized domain. You can keep trying.. eventuallt you'll get there